# How to compress a few files to zip in Qt?

Tags: qt, compression, zip

I need to zip a few files in Qt. I am trying Quazip. But the zip file contains files with 0kb size. Something goes wrong. Can somebody help me out here!
The code for zipping is given here:

```
QString testZip = location + "/tempTheme/test.zip";
            QuaZip zip(testZip);
            zip.setFileNameCodec("IBM866");            
            if(!zip.open(QuaZip::mdCreate)) {
              qWarning("testCreate(): zip.open(): %d", zip.getZipError());
            }
            zip.setComment("Test comment");
            QFileInfoList files=QDir(location + "/tempTheme/").entryInfoList();
            QFile inFile;
            QuaZipFile outFile(&zip);
            char c;
            foreach(QFileInfo file, files) {
              if(!file.isFile()||file.fileName()=="test.zip") continue;
              inFile.setFileName(file.fileName());
              if(!inFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
                qWarning("testCreate(): inFile.open(): %s", inFile.errorString().toLocal8Bit().constData());
              }
              if(!outFile.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly, QuaZipNewInfo(inFile.fileName(), inFile.fileName()))) {
                qWarning("testCreate(): outFile.open(): %d", outFile.getZipError());
              }
              while(inFile.getChar(&c)&&outFile.putChar(c));
              if(outFile.getZipError()!=UNZ_OK) {
                qWarning("testCreate(): outFile.putChar(): %d", outFile.getZipError());
              }
              outFile.close();
              if(outFile.getZipError()!=UNZ_OK) {
                qWarning("testCreate(): outFile.close(): %d", outFile.getZipError());
              }
              inFile.close();
            }
            zip.close();
            if(zip.getZipError()!=0) {
              qWarning("testCreate(): zip.close(): %d", zip.getZipError());
             QMessageBox msgInfo;
             msgInfo.information(this, "blah", "done");
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer, I need to make changes as following,

```
QString testZip = location + "/test.zip";
            QuaZip zip(testZip);
            zip.setFileNameCodec("IBM866");
            if(!zip.open(QuaZip::mdCreate)) {
              qWarning("testCreate(): zip.open(): %d", zip.getZipError());
            }
            //zip.setComment("Test comment");
            QFileInfoList files=QDir(location + "/tempTheme/").entryInfoList();
            QFile inFile;
            QFile inFileTmp;
            QuaZipFile outFile(&zip);
            char c;
            foreach(QFileInfo file, files) {
              if(!file.isFile()) continue;
              inFileTmp.setFileName(file.fileName());
              inFile.setFileName(file.filePath());
              if(!inFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
                qWarning("testCreate(): inFile.open(): %s", inFile.errorString().toLocal8Bit().constData());
              }
              if(!outFile.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly, QuaZipNewInfo(inFileTmp.fileName(), inFile.fileName()))) {
                qWarning("testCreate(): outFile.open(): %d", outFile.getZipError());
              }
              while(inFile.getChar(&c)&&outFile.putChar(c));
              if(outFile.getZipError()!=UNZ_OK) {
                qWarning("testCreate(): outFile.putChar(): %d", outFile.getZipError());
              }
              outFile.close();
              if(outFile.getZipError()!=UNZ_OK) {
                qWarning("testCreate(): outFile.close(): %d", outFile.getZipError());
              }
              inFile.close();
            }
            zip.close();
            if(zip.getZipError()!=0) {
              qWarning("testCreate(): zip.close(): %d", zip.getZipError());
            }
```

Comment: Thanks for giving the final solution in the end. :)

Answer (score 3):

If this project is just a toy, character-at-a-time is probably fine, but I can't imagine adding one million characters one-at-a-time to a zip file manager would be very efficient. And a one megabyte file looks mighty small these days. So hunt around the QuaZip API for mechanisms to either add files directly to the zip, or at least large buffers of data at a time. (Qt's buffering saves system calls but one million function calls working on one character vs 128 function calls working with 8k buffers is going to be noticeable in most programs.)

Comment: Now I have tried changing somethings and found out if(!inFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
                qWarning("testCreate(): inFile.open(): %s", inFile.errorString().toLocal8Bit().constData());
              }
This is throwing an error message saying the file doent exist. But the file is there when i checked? can you please tell what could be the reason for this. And btw if(0 == strcmp(file.fileName(), "test.zip"))
 this didnt work. threw error message saying about tht conversion between string const char is not possible! :(

Comment: That's just wrong, both QFileInfo::fileName() and QFile::fileName() return QString objects which has the == operator overloaded. It's perfectly fine to compare them with a char *.

Comment: @Wiz: Excellent! Thanks: http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qstring.html#operator-eq-eq-4

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned earlier, if it is a toy app its okay to write char-to-char. But in real it is really wasting resources.

My solution is:

```
(QuaZipFile) zipout->write( (QFile)inFile->readAll() );
```

It reads the entire file with QFile than writes out with QuaZipFile.